# how php handles multiple http requests

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I am developing a project which is related to credit card processing. Developing a server in php which will accept card number from another php page(this php page gives card number to php server from database).

The problem is that there may be multiple users who will access my php page at the same time and will send the card number to server. How can I handle multiple requests?

I googled and found that curl does such things. But didn't get detailed information about it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You are asking about concurrent connections to the server?

Comment: for every request, a new instance is created. So you have to not worry about that. On shared server, you will have limited resources and hence limited instances.

Comment: How your question is related to cURL?

Comment: After accepting card number my server processes that card number i.e. does the required transaction using that card number. So if multiple requests are coming to the server concurrently, do I need to maintain queue? or what should I do?

Comment: You server already handles that for you just fine...

Comment: Do tell me 1 more thing that I am using xampp for developling this application. So does xampp handle concurrent requests?